# Force Python to Use 4 digit Unicode Encoding (CSV Writer)

Tags: javascript, python, csv, unicode

I'm using the CSV module with python 3. I open my output file

```
open(file_name, 'w', encoding="ascii", errors="backslashreplace")
```

and then write a Unicode string to the file. Unicode characters are replaced by a hex-representation such as:

> f\xfcr

Unfortunately my parser (JavaScript) doesn't understand this representation and wants something like

> f\u00FCr

instead (4-digit representation). Is there some clever way to achieve this or do I have to reopen the file, find all occurrences and change them by myself?

Clarification: I don't want to use the utf-8 encoding because the JavaScript parser doesn't understand it. I need to escape the Unicode characters!

Comment: I think you're looking for the "unicode-escape" encoding.

Comment: Wouldn't changing `encoding="ascii"` for `encoding="utf-8"` do the trick?

Comment: No then I get "für" which crashes my JS Parser. I need the \u encoding.
@PM2Ring How does that work with the CSV module?

Comment: Unfortunately, the  "unicode-escape" encoding produces `\x` encoding for characters in the range `\u007f` to `\u00ff`. However you can use `json.dumps` to create JavaScript-friendly strings. It will accept single strings, as well as dicts, lists or tuples. Eg, `import json; print(json.dumps('für'))` prints `"f\u00fcr"`.

Comment: An even safer version is `json.dumps('für', ensure_ascii=True)`

Comment: That works. Thank you. It is not ideal because I have to call it on every string and it does more than just escaping Unicode but I think I can make it work.

Comment: `ensure_ascii=True` is the default, so no need to specify it

Comment: Another option is `s.encode('unicode-escape').replace(b'\\x', b'\\u00')`, but it's noticeably slower than `json.dumps(s)[1:-1]` in my `timeit` tests. OTOH, it converts codepoints >= `2**16` to `\U` sequences, whereas as `json.dumps` produces a surrogate pair. Eg, `'\U0001F602'` converts to `b'\\U0001f602'` using `'unicode-escape'`, but `json.dumps` produces `'"\\ud83d\\ude02"'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Clarification: I don't want to use the utf-8 encoding because the JavaScript parser doesn't understand it.

How unfortunate you have to deal with such a dumb parser; it appears to treat CSV data as JSON data, rather than properly handle encoded data. That's very much not a standard.

You can encode each value to JSON then strip the quotes:

```
import json, csv

def json_escaped(obj):
    res = json.dumps(obj)
    if res[0] == res[-1] == '"':
        res = res[1:-1]
    return res

with open(file_name, 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in source:
        writer.writerow(map(json_escaped, row))
```

This works because JSON is (almost completely) a superset of Javascript (the [two exceptions](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset) the Python parser won't ever produce when leaving the default `ensure_ascii` setting to `True`).

`backslashreplace` can't work, because only Unicode code points from U+0100 through to U+D7FF and U+E000 - U+FFFF are encoded to `\uhhhh` escapes by it. Codepoints outside those ranges are either already ASCII, encoded as shorter escape codes (`\n`, `\xhh`, etc.) or *longer* escape codes (`\Uhhhhhhhh` for anything over `U+FFFF`).

The `json` encoder on the other hand, will only ever produce `\uhhhh` escape codes, using [UTF-16 surrogate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF) for codepoints over U+FFFF.

Demo:

```
>>> import csv
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> data = [3.14, 'Unicode face: \u0669(-\u032e\u032e\u0303\u2022\u0303.', 'Something with a non-BMP emoji: \U0001F47D']
>>> with StringIO() as output:
...     writer = csv.writer(output)
...     writer.writerow(map(json_escaped, data))
...     print(output.getvalue())
...
105
3.14,Unicode face: \u0669(-\u032e\u032e\u0303\u2022\u0303.,Something with a non-BMP emoji: \ud83d\udc7d
```

So, valid CSV is produced with anything outside the ASCII range converted to `\uhhhh` sequences.

Note that newlines characters will also be encoded (to `\n`), but if your parser is treating data as JSON or Javascript literals, then that should not be a problem.